# ¿Cómo subir múltiples archivos con multer y Vue2Dropzone?

Tags: fileupload, multer, dropzone.js

Estoy intentado subir múltiples archivos y tengo tanto multer como Vue2Dropzone configurados para soportar la subida de múltiples archivos, sin embargo me devuelve el siguiente error:

> {"name":"MulterError","message":"Unexpected field","code":"LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE","field":"images[0]","storageErrors":[]}

Este es mi **server.js**:

```
const multer = require('multer');

app.use(multer({dest: './uploads/'}).array('images', 6));
```

Este is mi cliente:
HTML:

```
<v-card>
                <v-card-text>
                    <dropzone class="grey--text"
                              enctype="multipart/form-data"
                              ref="VueDropzone"
                              id="dropzone"
                              style="border: 4px solid #3F51B5"
                              :options="dropzoneOptions">
                    </dropzone>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-text align="right">
                    <v-btn class="error white--text" @click="close">
                        Cancelar
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn class="success white--text" @click="upload">
                        <v-icon class="mr-2">cloud_upload</v-icon>
                        Subir
                    </v-btn>
                </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
```

**JS**:

```
 data() {
            return {
                dropzoneOptions: {
                    url: Constants.URL_BASE + Constants.API_VERSION + '/posts/upload',
                    maxFilesize: 2,
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                    paramName: 'images',
                    autoProcessQueue: false,
                    maxFiles: 6,
                    acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg",
                    uploadMultiple: true,
                    thumbnailHeight: 130,
                    thumbnailWidth: 130,
                    dictRemoveFile: 'Eliminar',
                    dictMaxFilesExceeded: 'máximo 6 archivos',
                    dictInvalidFileType: 'Sólo archivos tipo imagen',
                    dictDefaultMessage: "Arrastre las imagenes o clickee aquí",
                },
            }
        },
methods: {
    upload(){
       this.$refs.VueDropzone.processQueue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He podido solucionar el problema utilizado la propiedad any() en la configuración de multer en mi server, en vez de array('images', 6). Ademas de convertir los archivos a subir en un FormData en mi cliente